# Angular 2 ng2 How to use TypeScript enum inside template?

Tags: templates, typescript, angular, angular-ng-if

I have component for multiple filters with different types.
For type recognition I want to use enum with filter types. 
How to use enum inside template when sample below does'nt work?

I thought it should work by only importing enum inside component where I want to use this enum.

```
import { FilterType } from './types/FilterType';
```

And use it inside template like `FilterType.INPUT_SELECT` and `FilterType.INPUT_TEXT` but it does'nt work then I used variable but it also does'nt work.

```
<div *ngFor='let filter of filters'>
  <select *ngIf='filter.type === checkType.INPUT_SELECT'>...</select>
  <input *ngIf='filter.type === checkType.INPUT_TEXT'></input>
</div>
...
export class FiltersComponent {
  checkType: FilterType;
  @Input() filters: any[];
}
...
export enum FilterType {
  INPUT_SELECT,
  INPUT_TEXT
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to assign a value to `checkType:

```
checkType: FilterType = FilterType;
```

Comment: Type 'typeof FilterType' is not assignable to type 'Type'

Comment: Sorry, I assumed a reference to an enum would be of type `Type`. I don't know TS too well I use only Dart locally. You can use `any`. `Object` should work as well.

Comment: It works but now I see it in different view, I will pass this enum as parameter. Thanks.

Comment: You can change type to `checkType: FilterType = FilterType;` or just `checkType = FilterType`